# Converting files for use in fragstats

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert, software-recommendations, fragstats

To use my data in fragstats i need to convert it into a signed integer grid.  I have the data in a raster format and have tried 'right click>data>export data> and setting the format to 'Grid' and it comes up with the error 'failed to save raster dataset'.  Any suggestions on how to convert either vector or raster data sets in to the format required for Fragstats?

Regards,

Comment: What software are you using for the data export?

Comment: Apologies, I have been trying to convert the data within ArcGIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool called "[Copy raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000)" to convert into grid in a more controlled way than export data. For GRID output the name of the output must not have any extension. With this tool, you can also define the pixel type "8_BIT_SIGNED".

If you start from vector, you can use [polygon to raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Polygon_to_Raster/001200000030000000/) in the conversion tools. Again, don't write any extension if you want a GRID as output.

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate what software you are exporting from, guessing from your export menu names, it's ArcGIS. If so, you can use the raster calculator to convert your raster into an unsigned integer using the 'int' function. to convert the vectors into raster, there is a tool in the conversion toolbox for converting vector data to raster format (conversion tools\to raster\polygon to raster).

*Edit: raster calculator is in the spatial analyst\map algebra toolbox

Answer (score 1):

The "failed to save" message sounds like disk write access or space availability issues. (and I definitely agree that using a more explicit function than the data>>export tool gives you better control over what comes out).